# Seeking excel formulas to make my life easier

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I am seeking help in working out a couple of excel formulas. I have included a snip of the data that I am working with and the outcome that I am seeking to streamline with the use of formulas.

[image: Excel query and output]

Ignoring column A. I want to copy the values from B & C but there are duplicate values in column B which I want to ignore, unless the value in column C is different for the value in column B. So I want to get the values across from B & C as per columns F & G). Then I want to sum the values from D, to be as per column H.

Hopefully you can decipher what I am after and provide some suggestions for how to tackle this.

General info: Windows 10, Excel 2016

Comment: Copy an paste columns B:C into F:G, use Remove Duplicates on the data tab.  Then use SUMIFS() to sum.

Comment: This is a typical job one would do with a pivot table.

Comment: Thanks Scott Craner, can't believe that it was that simple in the end - appreciate the response and solution. Houston

Comment: Thanks for the comment Máté, but I needed this in flat file format so that I can do further analysis on it. Scott had me covered though. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to do it with GAPS in the right hand columns (empty rows, no compression of the data like you have).

I do this all the time.  If I need to remove the blanks, I use COPY go to a new worksheet, and PASTE values, then I sort them, remove the dupes, or I manually delete those rows.  Depending on what I need.

Use a formula with an IF <>.  The first Row is Always included so:
F1=B1, G1=C1, H1=D1
then the formulas start
F2=IF(F1&G1<>B2&C2,B2,"")
G2=IF(F1&G1<>B2&C2,C2,"")
H2=IF(F1&G1<>B2&C2,D2,"")

Copy that all the way down and blank rows will be where the data matched the previous record.

I tested this, and added two SUMS() for the 2 numeric columns to show the difference in values

[image: My Version]

Comment: Thanks @CaptainKirk, I appreciate the time providing a solution to my query. If as you say you use this all the time then check out Scott's response above. It achieves what I was after without the spaces. A useful couple of tips. Cheers,